# Get Total Hard Disk Space of Remote Machine Using WMIC

Tags: wmic

I need to determine "TOTAL" hard disk space of the remote Windows host using `wmic` call.

I have tried executing `wmic /node:<IP-ADDRESS> diskdrive get Size` on some systems. For most of the systems, it worked well. But, for a few of them, it displayed multiple values, which are the total sizes of the partitions available.

```
H:\>wmic /node:172.22.248.112 diskdrive get size
Size
36273484800
293621594112
```

In order to get unique value for the total hard disk space (addition of sizes of all partitions), what should be done?

Comment: You have to add the individual sizes if you want to use this and get a total.  Batch only goes up to just less than 2 GB in maths but it can call a VBS script to do the calculation.

Comment: Where is the "batch file" part of this question? You're running it directly from the command line; there's no "batch file" involved here. Use the tags that actually apply to your question (and, conversely, **do not** use those that are not applicable).

Comment: Actually, I am using this command in a batch file. Instead of making the query more complicated, I preferred to ask the main point of concern.

Comment: Try this command, use value from 'Size' field (in bytes) and convert to MB or GB: wmic /node:192.168.56.1 path win32_diskdrive get /all /format:csv >"c:\windows\temp\win32_diskdrive.csv"

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
C:\>wmic /node:<IP-ADDRESS> logicaldisk get Size
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer